# Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'customer_name'

Tags: python, django, serialization

Please check me this error with serializers.
I have two model Customer and Factor:

models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=120 ,verbose_name='بنام')
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0, default=0, verbose_name='مبلغ کل فاکتور')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer_name}'

class Factor(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120 ,verbose_name='صورتحساب')
    name = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='بنام' ,related_name='factor_set')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200 ,verbose_name='شرح کالا')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0, default=0.0,verbose_name='قیمت واحد')
    count =models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=0, default=1,verbose_name='تعداد')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,null=True,verbose_name='تاریخ')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

serializer.py:

```
class FactorModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Factor
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    factor_set=FactorModelSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
class GetAllData__(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
      query = Customer.objects.all()
      serializer=CustomerModelSerializer(query)
      return Response(serializer.data ,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py :

```
from factor.views import GetAllData,GetAllData__

urlpatterns = [
    path('get-all-data--', GetAllData__.as_view()),

]
```

error :

AttributeError at /get-all-data--
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `customer_name` on serializer `CustomerModelSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'customer_name'.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide `source`  as 'factor_set' since Your serializer is searching from where to to put customer_name

```
class FactorModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Factor
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    factor_set=FactorModelSerializer(many=True,source='factor_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Now gives this error:       It is redundant to specify `source='factor_set'` on field 'ListSerializer' in serializer 'CustomerModelSerializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.

Comment: what happens if your remove source?

Comment: error :   Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `factor_set` on serializer `CustomerModelSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'factor_set'.

Comment: ListSerializer where is it?

Comment: can the solution be in class based views?

Comment: I removed the source and at CustomerModelSerializer  --> fields = ['customer_name','final_price','factor_set']

Comment: now error:  Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `customer_name` on serializer `CustomerModelSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on

Comment: the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'customer_name'.

Comment: When I debug in pycharm, an error appears in def get(self,request) part

Comment: I found :)))   ,cleaned many=True at name = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)